# My autocomplete only displays the last entry in my json array

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am not familiar with Jquery or JSON so I was happy I got this far with trying to build and auto complete search but in my search suggestions box only the last entry in the JSON response comes up.

Here are my scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-box").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "readCountry.php",
            data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
            }
        });
    });
});
    

function selectCountry(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="name" />
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<?php
include '../classes/conn.php';  
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT app_fName FROM ia_application.kpp_comments WHERE app_fName LIKE :keyword');
    $stmt->execute(array(':keyword' => $keyword));
    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if (! empty($result)) {
        ?>
<ul id="country-list">
   <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $result["app_fName"]; ?>');">
      <?php echo $result["app_fName"]; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
    <?php
    }
    }
 echo json_encode($result); 
?>
```

any guidance would be very appreciated.
Twiggit

Comment: There's no need for the `if (!empty($result))` condition. That's already tested by the `while` condition.

Comment: `echo json_encode($result);` is useless. After the loop is done, the value of `$result` is `false`.

Comment: Don't start a new  `<ul>` each time through the loop. Just create one `<ul>`, and each row should be `<li>`. But you should still see all the results.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you only see one response. If you use the Elements inspector, do you see the other ones?

Comment: try like this: `<?php
 include '../classes/conn.php';  
 $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
 $keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT app_fName FROM ia_application.kpp_comments WHERE app_fName LIKE :keyword');
 $stmt->execute(array(':keyword' => $keyword));
 $html = '<ul id="country-list">';
?>

<?php
 while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $html .= '<li onClick="selectCountry('.$result["app_fName"].');">'.$result["app_fName"].'</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo json_encode($html);
?>`

Comment: Barmar's suggestions helped me narrow down the issue and it seemed like the problem was the poorly formed UL.  Rookie mistake.
Thank you both.